# How to create a List Price Sheet filtered with Last Date Modified column in Dynamics-NAV

Tags: excel, report, microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-nav

I'm trying to generate a List Price Sheet report using the Dynamic NAV gui, which is located under Departments > Sales & Marketing > Inventory & Pricing.

Under the Reports and Analysis there is an option called List Price Sheet, which we use to create the price lists as Excel Files.

What I would like to do is to return only items that has been created or modified during an specific year, instead of having a list of all Items in the ItemCard.

When I add the Last Date Modified as a filter, it does not matter what value I enter, it keeps giving me a warning saying...

```
One or more filters are not valid and will be ignored. Do you want to continue?
```

Is there's a way I can accomplish that using the GUI or this is something that needs to be done with a custom function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry I did not provided more depth information, the problem was, that I was trying to search as string the value "2015", which is not a valid parameter to pass when searching a DateTime column. I have to search using a Date range, cause I wanted to get the result for the specific year 2015, in my case, the value I should've pass was:

```
01/01/2015..12/31/2015
```

Which return all items that has been modified during this specific year. After doing that I found out that every time NAV developers updated the production site with the test site, all items were marked as modified the date the update occurred. So was not of use for me any way.

Answer (score 0):

this "List Price Sheet" is not a standard report (NAV has a standard set of reports for every modules) therefore we can't help. You should contact your (=your company's) NAV partner for help.
Maybe if you can share the warning/error what you getting when entering the date I can help. Here is a link which maybe helps : [Entering Dates and Times in Dynamics NAV](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh179519(v=nav.80).aspx)

Cheers!

Comment: sorry but I wasn't able to access log error information... it is not in my pay range... :), but I entered the error I was getting in the pop-up alert, which does not supply this information either.